# Using an application page to programmatically add a property to a SharePoint web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages, properties

Apologies, this is definitely a can't see the woods for the tree's moment!

Can someone kindly remind me the *correct* way of adding/modifying a property bag entry on the current SPWeb object from an custom application page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check following for the extension methods around property bags:

http://expectedexception.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/manage-spweb-propertybag-from-c-code-and-sharepoint-designer/

You can run this code on button click or page load as per your requirement.

You can get SPWeb object on application page as this.Web

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after: `this.Web` **facepalm moment**

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in **C#**

```
static void AddWebKey(SPWeb web, string key, string value)
{
   if(web.Properties.ContainsKey(key))
   {
       web.Properties.Remove(key);
   }

   web.Properties.Add(key, value);

   web.Update();
}
```

For completeness, you can also do this from **PowerShell** if you really want:

```
function AddWebKey($web, $key, $value) {
    if($web.Properties.ContainsKey($key)) {
        $web.Properties.Remove($key)
    }

    $web.Properties.Add($key, $value)

    $web.Update()    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not really what you were asking for, but if you are looking for a easy way to administrate and add properties, take a look at this.

[SharePoint Property Bag Settings 2013](http://pbs2013.codeplex.com) - The SharePoint Property Bag offers developers to store configurations settings at different levels of the SharePoint hierarchy outside of the application itself.

I'm using this myself and it works perfectly if you wish to add properties from the site settings in the UI. There is versions for 2010 and 2007 as well. Deployed as a farm solution.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Indeed and have and use the same myself, however my requirement was to support something to be delegated to "Moderators" in a Community Site.